# Lower estimate on length of boundary of 2d Riemannian surface

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, surfaces, isoperimetric-problems

Fix constants $\kappa\in \mathbb{R}, D>0,A>0$. **Does there exist a constant $C>0$ depending on $\kappa, D, A$ only such that for any compact 2-dimensional Riemannian surface (or more generally Alexandrov space) of Gauss curvature at least $\kappa$, diameter at most $D$, area at least $A$, and locally geodesically convex non-empty boundary, the length of the boundary is at least $C$?**

One can show (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279705/estimate-of-number-of-boundary-components-of-a-compact-riemannian-2-surface)) that under the above assumptions the number of connected components of the boundary is bounded above. I would ask a stronger question:**is the length of each connected component of the boundary is bounded below by $C$?**

Remark. I think that both versions of the above question should follow from the Gromov compactness theorem and a strong version of the Perelman stability theorem (and few other results from Alexandrov geometry). The latter says that a GH-convergent non-collapsing sequence of compact Alexandrov spaces with uniform lower bound on curvature and upper bound on dimension for large indices is bi-Lipschitz homeomorphic to the limit space. However the details of a proof of this result have never been published, so I am wondering if there is a more direct and elementary proof. I am not a specialist, so I may miss something well known.